# Azure "No CNAME records were found. Please add a CNAME record pointing to "

Tags: networking, dns, azure, cname

I am trying to create a new site with a given test.*.net subdomain for a client. I created the web app in Azure and gave them the IP address that the azure said to give and they somehow linked it because when I do an nslookup, it shows the Azure IP address
[image]

But when I go into Custom Domains and try to link it, I get the error "No CNAME records were found. Please add a CNAME record pointing to test[mysite123].azurewebsites.net". I believe they didn't properly follow all of the steps as outlined [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-a-cname-record) but what do I need to tell them to do specifically because I already asked them to add a CNAME record and it looks in nslookup like they did something but Azure still is not happy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: DNS changes take time to propagate. Its possible it simply takes a bit longer. How quickly after they made the changes did you try it?

Comment: I'm aware of the time lag. Sorry, I should have mentioned more info about that. I read to allow up to 48 hours to allow them to propogate but it has been about 4 days now, so I think we can rule that out as a culprit.

Comment: @DanCsharpster If possible, could you share your Domains CNAME settings in your question. Of course, remove sensitive information.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that without sharing my client's sensitive info, like their actual domain name and such. I could DM it to you.